# What is the difference between consume the result from await and return the result from await?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I am a bit confused by the two following code snippets:

```
async function f() {

  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 1000)
  });

  let result = await promise; // wait until the promise resolves (*)

  return result; 
}
console.log(f()); //prints Promise { <pending> } at once then wait for 1 second before terminating
```

And

```
async function f() {

  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 1000)
  });

  let result = await promise; // wait until the promise resolves (*)

  console.log(result); 
}

f(); //waits for 1 second and prints done! before terminating
```

I was expecting the two code snippets above to produce the same result, e.g. print done! to the console after 1 second. What made the first code snippet return

Comment: You need to use `await` on `f` as well e.g. `await f()` for it to return what value the promise holds.

Comment: #1 logs a promise because `async` functions always return promises. If you want to interact with the eventual value of that promise, either call `.then` on the promise, or put your code in an `async` function and `await` the promise.

Comment: Nitpick: *"wait until the promise resolves"* No, it waits until the promise *settles*. A promise can be resolved but still be unsettled (aka pending) and in fact they often are. For the distinction, see my short article [Let's talk about how we talk about promises](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/02/08/lets-talk-about-how-to-talk-about-promises/).

Comment: you can achieve the same effect in the first case by writing `console.log(await f()); ` instead of `console.log(f()); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What made the first code snippet return

Both code snippets return at the same point. The `await` keyword, when it gets a promise on the RHS, makes the function it belongs to go to sleep until that promise settles.

Meanwhile, the calling function gets the promise returned by `f` and continues running.

That's the point of using `async` functions: They **don't block** when they are dealing with something asynchronous.